# Magento: Cant get product collection use custom attribute filter?

Tags: php, magento

I have a collection of products in my magento catalog that are tagged as samplers. I need to pull back this specific collection. The attribute is part of an attribute set called candies.

When I go to load the collection, I add a filter to narrow by the attribute set, and then add another filter for the sampler attribute I created. No matter what I do with the filter, I always get back ALL the candies not just the ones with the attribute of sampler set to "yes" or 1.

Here is my code, how do I get the result I am looking for?

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  //select all fields available to product
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', 9) //filter the collection by the candies attribute set
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sampler','yes'); //filter the collection to only products that have the attribute sampler set to "yes" - this part doesnt work.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use flat tables? Is the `sampler` attribute part of the flat tables? If not, your question will be more complicated than just applying the Zend comparison operator correctly as mentioned in [alex's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32173792/2812842)

Comment: Hello. I do use flat tables for our Magento store. However, I do not see the field in the db when I look at those tables. I tried reindexing the flat catalog to see if that would add the field and no dice. Any idea how to force a full rebuild of those tables?

Comment: Funny enough - if I turn off flat data it works! Turn it back on, and it fails even after rebuilding all the pertinent indexes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: http://gielberkers.com/magento-attributes-missing-using-flat-catalog/

After considering the comments here, I would try this setting.

Comment: didn't work for me. I must not be using the flat table?

Comment: Which Magento version do you have ?

Comment: In Magento 1, go to admin backend, then system -> configuration. Then Catalog on the left menu, then look for `Use Flat Catalog Product`. This tells if you are using flat table for products or not.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have iterate over the collection.  Load the id of each product, then use ->getAttributeText('').

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
    ;
    foreach ($collection as $_product) {
        $id =  $_product->getId();
        if($tncValue = $_product->load($id)->getAttributeText('terms_and_conditions')){
            echo $id . ' => ' . $tncValue . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', 9)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sampler', array('eq' => '1'));
?>
```

Comment: try the above code **`->addAttributeToFilter('sampler', array('eq' => '1'))`** instead of this `->addAttributeToFilter('sampler','yes')`

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I had tried the operator operation that you provided before posting the question. It didnt work. I also changed addAttributeToFilter to addFieldToFilter with the same lack of luck.